# PHP validation code not working for age?

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, settings

I have a user that just logged in and I sessioned the age of the user because it's needed for the validation that I'm doing. Once a user is logged in he will be redirected to a page that has a table that displays surveys that he can take. When admin is creating a survey, there's an option of age range meaning only certain people with this age can take the survey

```
<select name="agestart" class="form-control-static">      

<label> TO </label>

<select name="ageend" class="form-control-static">
```

Now I'm trying to do a validation/setting that will get the user to be only able to see surveys that match their age range.

```
 <?php



    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "imetrics");

    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM surveyform");

    if($query){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

            $id = $row['survey_id'];
            $title = $row['surveytitle'];
            $agestart = $row['age_start'];
            $ageend = $row['age_end'];

            if(!$_SESSION['age'] >= $agestart || $_SESSION['age'] <= $ageend ){

                echo "<tr align='center'>";
                echo "<td><font color='black'>" . $id . "</font></td>";
                echo "<td><font color='black'>" . $title . "</font></td>";
                echo "<td><a href='preview.php?survey_id=$id'><input class='btn btn-danger' type='button' value='Take Survey'/></td>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

But it seems there's something wrong with my condition since it's only working (not displaying) if the users age is higher than agestart and ageend I THINK. I'm really confused at the moment.

```
if(!$_SESSION['age'] >= $agestart || $_SESSION['age'] <= $ageend ){
```

Comment: starting the session would help

Comment: Also, removing `!` and changing `||` for `&&` in the `if` condition

Comment: @Fred-ii- This isn't the full document apparently; OP says the condition behaves weird, so this isn't a session problem.

Comment: @ChrisG question's too unclear and as to why they have `<select>`'s and if they intend on using those to rely on the query.

Comment: Thank you for the info sirs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things, either add session_start(); and fix your conditions or alter your SQL query.

```
session_start();
$sessionAge = $_SESSION['age'];

$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM surveyform WHERE $sessionAge BETWEEN age_start AND age_end");  

// OR with a condition

if(($agestart <= $sessionAge) && ($sessionAge <= $ageend)) {
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the proper way to do the age check:

```
$age = intval($_SESSION['age']);
if ($agestart <= $age && $age <= $ageend) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir @Chris G it worked! I will vote up this answer once I'm above 15 reputations.

Comment: Thanks, but make sure to look at Yolo's answer for a way to include the age check in the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you did not start the session yet:

```
session_start(); //Should be at the beginning of the file
```

Please note that `$_SESSION['age']` should have a value:

```
$age = (isset($_SESSION['age'])) ? $_SESSION['age'] : 0; //For PHP < 7.x
$age = $_SESSION['age'] ?? 0; //For PHP 7
```

Answer (score 0):

The boolean condition is incorrectly written; I know logically this is equivalent to the above answers, but IMHO this is easier to read:

```
if($_SESSION['age'] >= $agestart && $_SESSION['age'] <= $ageend)
```

Maybe I am old-school, but `$agestart <= $age && $age <= $ageend` may be harder for most to quickly read and understand.